# Trouble configuring custom folder for site (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I'm trying to configure httpd on fedora, but my two day effort has gotten me nowhere.
I installed httpd and php, added the configuration file for the site, everything is fine. I try to load it and see "access denied." but I have already granted to the apache user and apache group 755 rights (on every folder along the path).

Errors in apache log:

> [Mon Jun 06 20:25:18.088420 2022] [negotiation:error] [pid 12656:tid
> 12758] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:45920] AH00686: cannot
> read directory for multi: /home/concasse_master/Desktop/sample/public/
>
> [Mon Jun 06 20:25:18.089421 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12656:tid
> 12758] [client 127.0.0.1:45920] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open
> primary script: /home/concasse_master/Desktop/sample/public/index.php
> (Permission denied)'

localhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/concasse_master/Desktop/sample/public
    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/concasse_master/Desktop/sample/public/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```